# rule cannot be matched when using flex "||"

Tags: flex-lexer

If I delete the line 41 then that was no warning

> "lex.l", line 41: warning, rule cannot be matched
>
> line 41: "||" {printf("26,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}

```
digit [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
id ({letter}|[_])({letter}|{digit}|[_])*
%%
[ |\t|\n]+
"var" {printf("28,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"if" {printf("29,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"then" {printf("30,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"else" {printf("31,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"while" {printf("32,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"for" {printf("33,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"begin" {printf("34,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"writeln" {printf("35,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"procedure" {printf("36,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"end" {printf("37,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
{id} {printf("1,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
{digit}+ {printf("2,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}

...

"+=" {printf("23,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"-=" {printf("24,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"==" {printf("25,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"||" {printf("26,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
"&&" {printf("27,\"%s\"\n",yytext);}
%%
#include <ctype.h>
int main(){
    yylex ( );
    return 0 ;
}
yywrap(){
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
[ |\t|\n]
```

Is a character class, which matches one of the following four characters:

- *space*
- Vertical bar (<kbd>|</kbd>)
- *tab*
- *newline*

The vertical bar appears twice in the class, but since a character class is a set, the repetition is ignored.

So

```
[ |\t|\n]+
```

matches any non-empty sequence consisting only of the above characters. One such sequence is `||`. Since that rule comes before the `"||"` rule, it will be used to match `||` and thus the rule `"||"` cannot ever be matched, as the warning says.

You should seriously consider using `[[:space:]]` to match any whitespace character, `[[:alpha:]]` to match a letter and `[[:digit:]]` to natch a digit. Those are more self-documenting than trying to write out the set. But if you are going to write out the set, don't include a vertical bar unless you mean to include it.

Flex patterns are documented in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns). It's worth reading.

Comment: thx a lot:) I have already known why the warning happen but what should I do to solve this problem

Comment: @huhao: remove the erroneous vertical bars from the character class. Or (better IMHO) use `[[:space:]]` instead.